# Searching for multiple keywords in one line

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, grep

I would like to know if there anyway to force "grep"-command to search for multiple keywords in the same string or line.
Example:
 let's say that i have the following block-text:

```
 CT1   CD    750.000     1.2200 
 OB    CD    750.000     1.2200 
 OB    H     545.000     0.9600 
 CT1   CD   CP1   70.000    125.00   20.00   2.44200 ! ALLOW ALI PEP POL ARO PRO
 OB    CD   CT1   70.000    125.00   20.00   2.44200 ! ALLOW   ALI PEP POL ARO
```

and I am searching for lines that contains only "OB" and "CD". So the output I expect is:

```
 OB    CD    750.000     1.2200 
 OB    CD   CT1   70.000    125.00   20.00   2.44200 ! ALLOW   ALI PEP POL ARO
```

However, when i use the command: `grep "OB \| CD" file1`
 I will get the whole block-text.

So, is there any combination that reduces the output in the way I want?

Many thanks in advance.

P.S.: I use linux and os 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/OB/ && /CD/' file1
```

```
awk '/OB.*CD/' file1
```

This will only print lines with `OB` and `CD`.  Last example `OB` need to come before `CD`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `egrep`.  DO it by

```
egrep "(OB|CD)" file1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of keywords matters:

```
grep 'OB.*CD' file1
```

If you want the keywords in any order:

```
grep "OB" file1 | grep "CD"
```

`grep "OB \| CD" file1` returned all lines because it had logical OR instead of AND.